# How to change dateformat?

Tags: angular

```
 for (let entry of data) {
        trHtml += `<tr>
                        <td>` + '1' + `</td>
                        <td>` + entry.servicecode + `</td>
                        <td>` + entry.servicename + `</td>
                        <td>` + entry.duedate  + `</td>
                        <td>` + entry.installmentamount + `</td>
                        <td>` + '1' + `</td>

                    </tr>`;
    }
```

I have this loop. What i want is to for `entry.duedate` add `| date:'shortdate'`, but in this case i cant because im getting error:

> Forbidden bitwise operation (no-bitwise)

Comment: Why are you doing this in code? Can't you use a template?

Comment: Will you please set a plunker ?

Comment: @Henry im using this in document.write because im creating template for printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simple solution :

```
for (let entry of data) {
        let date : Date=<Date>entry.duedate;
        let day=date.getDate();
        let month= date.getMonth()+1;
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        let dateString : String = day+"/"+month+"/"+year; // if u want dd/mm/yyyy for example   
        trHtml += `<tr>
                      <td>` + '1' + `</td>
                      <td>` + entry.servicecode + `</td>
                      <td>` + entry.servicename + `</td>
                      <td>` + dateString  + `</td>
                      <td>` + entry.installmentamount + `</td>
                      <td>` + '1' + `</td>
                   </tr>`;
 }
```